# duda foreach controller laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo la necesidad de aplicar un loop en un controlador, pero pues no se si sea adecuado hacerlo asi

```html
  public function reportes(Request $request)
    { 
       
        $reporuser=usuarios::pluck('usuario_ad', 'user_id')->unique();

        foreach($reporuser as $reporusers)



        endforeach

        return  view('usuario.reportes',compact('userstarea'));
    }
```

O hay otra manera de hacer un loop.

Comment: cual es el resultado que estas tratando de obtener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola zeref te acomodo un poco tu codigo, espero te sirva de referencia:

```
public function reportes(Request $request)
{ 

    $reporuser= usuarios::pluck('usuario_ad', 'user_id')->unique();
    // hasta donde tengoconocimiento pluck se usa para collections y estas haciendo un eloquent query 
    $reporuser= usuarios::where('usuario_ad','=', $request['user_id'])->get();
    // con este deberias traer todos los que tengan el mismo "user_id"

    foreach($reporuser as $rp)
    {
      echo $rp->ColName;
    }

    return  view('usuario.reportes',compact('userstarea'));

}
```

saludos.

Comment: no entiendo tus dos consultas que haces al inicio

Comment: además de esa duda, dime por que haces un echo, si los datos son para la vista?

Comment: y la ultima duda yo veo que mandas a la vista una variable `userstarea` pero no veo que exista en todo tu código

Comment: Es cierto shadow.. ahi no hay codigo completado, apenas lo estoy haciendo, es solo que queria estar entender, como un controlador maneja un loop..